# How to use non-visual subcomponents to define component properties?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have implemented a data-grid like component in vue.js (that renders an html table, but that is not important). The usage is like:

```
<ex-table :header="listHeader" :data="listData" ></ex-table>
```

where header is an array type property of the ex-table, describing all the columns of the grid (for eaxample: header text, which field of data to display, if the column is sortable, filterable, etc.).

I would like to change the component, so that it can be used/defined like this:

```
<ex-table :data="listData">
  <ex-columns>
    <ex-column header="Column1" field="dataField1" sortable="true" filterable="false">
    <ex-column header="Column2" field="dataField2" sortable="true" filterable="true">
    ...
  </ex-columns>
</ex-table>
```

In other words, instead of a header array, describe the columns as a list of ex-column subcomponents, that are not visible, they are only there to define how the grid will look like.

My question is: how can I get access to these subcomponents in the ex-table?

I am pretty new to vue.js. I have looked into child components and slots, but they do not seem to be the solution.
I just do not know how I can access the ex-columns in the my ex-table template / render method so that I can use the data from there (similarly as I use the header array in my current solution).

Comment: **1/2:** Personally, I think this is taking the long way around. I have been pondering how to do this, and I cannot think of an easy way. You're basically wanting to use `slots` to pass data to a component, but this  is exactly what `props` are for. It would be difficult to accomplish this. To me, it makes more sense to allow the user to supply an `options` object containing these parameters. Something like this seems (ignore everything outside of how the component is being used) a lot easier to accomplish - for both you and the person using it: [see next post for link]

Comment: **2/2:** [Something like this](https://appdividend.com/2018/06/07/vue-datatable-component-example/#Step_7_Send_an_Axios_GET_request) table seems easier. Allowing the user to pass in an options property makes the most sense to me, especially if you aren't wanting the `slots` to style anything or render any `html` that gets passed in: `<v-client-table :data="tableData" :columns="columns" :options="options"></v-client-table>`

Comment: It seems that something similar is implemented in ag-grid: https://www.ag-grid.com/best-vuejs-data-grid/#declarative_definition, but I still don't know how.

Comment: @MattOestreich the advantage in such a solution would be to use bindings in the ex-column properties (for example for a visible property where the user can show/hide a column).